# Bootstrap Jquery Timepicker

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement a check in check out date-picker also I'm not good with Jquery I'm having some problems making it run. I've also checked if the jquery is loading and it does can someone help me on what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var nowTemp = new Date();
        var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

        var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
          onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
          if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            checkout.setValue(newDate);
          }
          checkin.hide();
          $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
        }).data('datepicker');
        var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
          onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
          checkout.hide();
        }).data('datepicker');


        });



         </script>
        </head>
        <body onload>
        <div class="well" id="div1">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Check in: <input type="text" class="span2" value="" id="dpd1"></th>
                    <th>Check out: <input type="text" class="span2" value="" id="dpd2"></th>
```

Comment: Please add your complete code in jsfiddle..

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iTonzkie/KMRsm/)

Comment: did you checked my answer??? working code is there in fiddle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not connected to plugin js files. it will not work without including needed external Resources.

```
      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

     <script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css">
```

Please check this working example with your code.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymp5D/26/)

add needed external resources.